# How to Bypass auv_control for BlueROV2 in ROS2

Tags: ros2, pid, rosnode, rostopic--pub

I installed a [simulator](https://github.com/CentraleNantesROV/bluerov2) for the BlueROV2 and I was able to control manual both the thrusters and/or the pose with the given GUI.

However I would like to overwrite the pose through a script.
 I made a node that published messages in the `cmd_pose` rostopic  (since it is the once that controls the pose of the bluerov) but the PID Controller published messages much faster than my node.
 As a result I am not able to control the robot, it resets in the position from the GUI.

If someone has been able to manual control the bluerov2 through the `cmd_pose` rostopic please let me know how to do it.